# Array object and element?

Tags: java, arrays, object

this class works:

```
public class Undergrad extends Student{
    private int year;
    private int numOfCourses=0;
    private Course[] courses=new Course[4];
    public Undergrad(int year,String name,String major,double gpa){
        super(name,major,gpa);
        this.year=year;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year=year;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getMajor(){
        return major;
    }
    public double getGpa(){
        return gpa;
    }
    public void setGpa(double gpa){
        this.gpa=gpa;
    }
    public Course[] getCourses(){
        return courses;
    }
    public void addCourses(Course course){
        if(numOfCourses>=4){
            System.out.println("Student can not study");
        } else{
            courses[numOfCourses]=course;
            numOfCourses++;
        }
    }

    public void printCourses(){
        for(int i=0;i<numOfCourses;i++){
            System.out.println(courses[i].toString());

        }
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Student name"+name+"courses"+numOfCourses;
    }
 }
```

but I was just wondering shouldn't "course" have an "s" so it becomes courses, so it can become the same as the name in the array "courses". Also is the printCourse method the same as the System.out.print method?

```
 public void addCourses(Course course)
```

Comment: No, it's becoming the parameter handed to addCourses in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Course` is simply the name of the class. Even if there are plenty of `Course` objects, the name stays the same.

As of `courses` is the name of the **object's reference** so you're free to choose it while creating it.

---

If your question is why in `addCourses(Course course)` course does not have an s, it is because it is a reference to a `Course` object and not to the array.

```
courses[numOfCourses]=course
```

Here, we're adding `course` to the `courses` array of `Course` objects.

Comment: okay so here (Course course) , course is an element and it can be named anything

Answer (score 0):

To your question, it doesn't really make any difference. Your 'addCourses' method is not a setter or getter method, so should in future you want to use the class for any purposes that imply serialization you will be fine.

But just for readability you could rename it to void addCourse(Course c).

In addition, you could guard against potential null argument using the Optional class added in Java 8.

```
public void addCourse(Course c){
    if(numOfCourses>=4){
            System.out.println("Student can not study");
        } else{
            courses[numOfCourses]=Optional.ofNullable(c).orElse(new Course(argument 1, argument 2, argument etc));
            numOfCourses++;
        }
}
```